# How can I return a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c

```
char **splitWords(){
    
    FILE *inp;
    char **arr[1000][30];
    int i = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    char c;
    int char_count = 0;

    inp = fopen("C:\\Users\\ksmcn\\Desktop\\free.txt", "r");
    
    while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
          //  printf("\n");

            arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
            char_count = 0; //Reset the counter.
            word_count++;
        }
        else {
            **arr[word_count][char_count] = c; 
        //  printf("%c",arr[word_count][char_count]);

             if (char_count < 99)
                 char_count++;
             else
                 char_count = 0;
        }   
    }
    fclose(inp);
    return **arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    char **array[1000][30];   
    char array = splitWords();
   
    return 0;
}
```

I want to return a two dimensional array using c programming. My `splitWords` function stores words as elements of an array and there is no issue about it. However I couldn't return my array to work in main function. Please help!

Comment: `char array = splitWords();` is a (duplicate) declaration of variable `array`.  Leave out the leading `char` for a simple assignment.  That is not the only issue here, however.

Comment: The assignment `arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0';` implies that you think `arr` was declared as `char arr[N][M];`. But it was not.  `'\0'` is not a `char **`, and your compiler should warn you about this error.

Comment: Tidbit: `char c` really ought to be `int c`

Comment: @ksmcnns, `char **` is a _pointer_ type, not an _array_.  In C, functions cannot return arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> ```c
> char **arr[1000][30];
> ```

You're declaring a 2D array of pointers to `char` pointers? I think you mean `char arr[1000][30]`. If you really do mean what this is, you are only initializing the space for a pointer, not the actual content of the pointer.

> ```c
> inp = fopen("C:\\Users\\ksmcn\\Desktop\\free.txt", "r");
> ```

You should add a sanity check in case the file couldn't be opened. In other words, check if `inp` is `NULL`.

> ```c
> arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
> ```

This will work if you declared `arr` as `char[][]`, but you declared it as `**char[][]`. See above.

> ```c
> **arr[word_count][char_count] = c;
> ```

If you're declaring `arr` as `char[][]`, you need `arr[word_count][char_count]`. With your current declaration, this would work.

> ```c
> if (char_count < 99)
> ```

Your array is only big enough to store 30 `char`s. Also, where's the check for if `word_count` exceeds 1000? Not to mention, if you reset `char_count`, then it will overwrite existing values!

> ```c
> return **arr;
> ```

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is UB if I recall correctly. If your array were declared as `char[][]`, you'd need to do `return arr`.

> ```c
> char **array[1000][30];
> ```

Why are you declaring something of type `char **[][]` when the function returns `char **`?

> ```c
> char array = splitWords();
> ```

Why are you redefining `array` as type `char`? This won't work! Not to mention (once again) `splitWords()` returns `char **`, not `char`.